# Append Text File last four days

Tags: c#, parsing, text-files

I have a small program that creates a simple text file as follow :

```
 string filename = "recdata.txt";

 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Append)))
                {
                    string cmdTxt = String.Format("{0},{1},{3}", CustomerName, CustomerPhone, TodayDateTime));
                    sw.WriteLine(cmdTxt);
                }
```

What I would like to do is to keep always the last four days of data in this file. For example, content of the file is as follow :

```
Four days recdata.txt file today (01/12/2014) is (please notice that on Jan 10 there were no data. Some days can or cannot contain data:

John Powell, 12154584435,01092014 10:30:27.33
Carol Powell, 12154584215,01092014 10:32:27.33
Peter Smith, 12154541411,01092014 10:34:27.33
John Powell, 12154584435,01112014 11:30:07.03
Albert Smith, 12124252211,01122014 07:33:02.22
Humphrey Powell, 17183544110,01122014 08:10:32.14
Jason Smith, 17183994741,01122014 10:00:07.01
Oliver Powell, 12123664435,01122014 10:11:21.21

Four Days recdata.txt file tomorrow should be (01/13/2014) :

John Powell, 12154584435,01112014 11:30:07.03
Albert Smith, 12124252211,01122014 07:33:02.22
Humphrey Powell, 17183544110,01122014 08:10:32.14
Jason Smith, 17183994741,01122014 10:00:07.01
Oliver Powell, 12123664435,01122014 10:11:21.21
Jimmy Memphis, 12142544111,01132014 14:15:10.01
```

Each day, this file is sent via ftp automatically and the recdata.txt is copied to an archive folder, e.g. recdata_01132014.txt

I can check for the date the file was created using File.GetCreationTime but should I need to read the entire file every day and then remove one day from the file or there is a better way? The data inside recdata.txt does not exist anywhere else apart of the copied file in the archive folder. Any thoughts will be gladly appreciate it thanks.

Comment: Why don't you put the log in a database like SQLite or MS Access? this way you can query records more easily base on date.

Comment: You can write data of each day to a separated file using the date. Then just concat what you want and delete the days you don't want. You can use DateTime.Subtract to get the last four days.

Comment: I have no access to any database Jade. Du D, do you mean I create a daily file and then create the recdata.txt by parsing and appending the daily files I need?

Comment: Ok after further thinking and moving things around, I am embedding a SQLite as it is much more reliable, thanks folks